# Specific zoom depending annotations

Tags: ios, swift

I am programming an Swift application and I work with the SDK Skobbler. I would like to know if it is possible to indicate a specific zoom depending annotations.
I would to have a accurate zoom...
I know that with the routing service, there is this function which doing automatically the zoom :

> routingService.zoomToRouteWithInsets(UIEdgeInsetsZero)

This is the app screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you need to set SKBoundingBox for specific bountry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK >= 3.0 (Skobbler >= 3.0)**

```
self.mapView: SKMapView = SKMapView()

let topLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.267034, longitude:  5.989881)
let bottomRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.248354, longitude: 6.013811)

let boundingBox = SKBoundingBox(topLeftCoordinate: topLeftCoord, bottomRightCoordinate: bottomRightCoord)

mapView.fitBounds(boundingBox, withInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100))
```

**For ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK < 3.0 (Skobbler < 3.0)**

```
self.mapView: SKMapView = SKMapView()

let topLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.267034, longitude:  5.989881)
let bottomRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.248354, longitude: 6.013811)

let boundingBox = SKBoundingBox(topLeftCoordinate: topLeftCoord, bottomRightCoordinate: bottomRightCoord)

mapView.fitBounds(boundingBox, withPadding: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
let boundingBox = SKBoundingBox(topLeftCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(track.ne.coordinate.latitude, track.sw.coordinate.longitude), bottomRightCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(track.sw.coordinate.latitude, track.ne.coordinate.longitude))

    // Add the mapView to the view just to see if it displays correctly. (It does!)
    mapView.fitBounds(boundingBox, withPadding: CGSizeMake(20, 20))
```